# Display Title and Image from RSS using php

Tags: php, xml, xslt, simplexml

I am trying to create a page that will display the title of an RSS story as well as an image. Every story has a title. Most have an image, but I only need to display the image(s) if they have a height and width set to "100". So far, I haven't had any success filtering the attributes. I'm very new to XML and inexperienced in PHP, but here's what I have so far:

```
    <? 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("./_resources/xml/news.rss");
    foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->title . "<br />\n";
        $value->registerXPathNamespace('media','http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
        //$result = $value->xpath('media:thumbnail[@height = "100"]');
        $result = $value->xpath('media:thumbnail/@url');
        echo '<img src="http:' . $result . '">' . "<br />\n";
        }
     ?>
```

The RSS is structured like so:

```
<channel>
     <title>Title Here</title>
     <description>Here's the description</description>
     <content:encode>Here's some content for you</content:encode>
     <media:thumbnail url="//www.website.com/images/img1.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
     <media:thumbnail url="//www.website.com/images/img2.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
```

As you can see, I tried looking for an attribute of height = "100", but had no luck.

I also need to make sure that I don't try to display an image if a 100x100 image isn't present, and make one using simplexml and one using XML/XSL Any tips?

EDIT:
I THINK I figured it out. It works, at least. Here's what I did:

```
<? 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("./_resources/xml/news.rss");
    foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->title . "<br />\n";
        $value->registerXPathNamespace('media','http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
        $result = $value->xpath('media:thumbnail[@height = "100"]/@url');
        if ($result != null){
            echo '<img src="http:' . $result[0] . '">' . "<br />\n";
            } else {
                echo '<img src="./images/noimage.jpg" height="100" width="100">' . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

So, it WORKS... I'm just not sure if it's considered "good code". Also, I'm supposed to do this 2 ways: Using simplexml, and then using XML/XSL. Not sure how to do it with the XML/XSL route, so I could still use a hand there. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have made some progress.

I updated the lines

`$result = $value->xpath('media:thumbnail/@url');
        echo '<img src="http:' . $result . '">' . "<br />\n";`


to


`$result = $value->xpath('media:thumbnail[@height = "100"]/@url');
      echo '<img src="http:' . $result[0] . '">' . "<br />\n";`

Now, I need to figure out how to not try to post an image if no 100x100 image is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your rss xml has a syntax error, the url attribute is not closed:

```
<media:thumbnail url="//www.website.com/images/img1.jpg width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: That's a typo on my part... there are closing quotes for the source in the RSS file.